# Retrieve users About Me (PersonImmersive.aspx) page from CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365

Is it possible to retrieve the O365 About Me data (in PersonImmersive.aspx) via REST or CSOM ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to retreive user profile properties via CSOM or REST. Yes this is possible.

You need to refer `SP.UserProfiles.js` in your javascript file and after that you can use the following code to fetch the properties. The code is taken from msdn site referred below:

```
var personProperties;

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {

// Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

// Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

// Get user properties for the target user.
// To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
// getMyProperties method.
personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

// Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
clientContext.load(personProperties);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {

// Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
    + personProperties.get_displayName();

// Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
    + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
$get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
$get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

For more details check these msdn links

1. [Using CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx)
2. [Using REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx)